# Is it possible to cast the contents of a C++17 stl collection?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I have a one-to-many relationship between two classes, where the owned classes can be of more than one type. The data model requires that a relationship in the superclass can be 'subsetted' in a subclass.

Each end of the relationship looks like this:

```
weak_ptr<Element> owner;
unordered_set<shared_ptr<Element>> ownedElements;
```

On the superclass, Element, there is a function:

```
unordered_set<shared_ptr<Element>> ownedElements();
```

And on a subclass there is a similar function:

```
unordered_set<shared_ptr<SubElement>> ownedSubElements();
```

In the implementation of `ownedSubElements()` I would like to cast the `unordered_set<shared_ptr<Element>>` to `unordered_set<shared_ptr<SubElement>>`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? What is your actual goal in trying to pull this off?

Comment: Good question. Maybe I shouldn't be trying to do this. I am trying to implement an existing model design that has this subset concept. An alternative would be to ignore the parent relationship functions (treat them as abstract), and just implement the leaf functions. That could result in some loss of functionality, but it mightn't be needed, and it does simplify the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<SubElement>> subElements;
std::transform(
    ownedElements.begin(), ownedElements.end(),
    std::inserter(subElements, subElements.end()),
    [](std::shared_ptr<Element> elem) {
      return std::static_pointer_cast<SubElement>(elem);
    });
```

This assumes that you know somehow that all elements in `ownedElements` do in fact point to a `SubElement` instance.

Comment: I can assume that ownedElements are a particular subclass, so I think this would work. I was hoping to avoid creating a new unordered_set, but it may be the only solution, and I think it would work. This may be the only way to do it.